# Lightning network routing failure rate

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing

Let's say a lightning node `A` wants to route a payment to a lightning node `B`, being `A` and `B` not directly connected.`A` looks for routes throughout the network, using the info about the total capacity of available channels and construct `n` possible routes to reach `B`.

Will `A` just try routes until eventually one of the `n` succeeds?

For what I've got by checking the [BOLTS](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc), the actual state of each sides of the channels is not announced (is it?), what means that even though a route could have enough capacity to route a payment, one of the channel could be unbalanced and the whole route may fail. Therefore, the potential failure rate when trying to route payments seems quite high.

Am I missing something?

Comment: the pay-request could be generated in such a way that it contains the routes hints! so i would help yo get the right route! sorry, this is more a comment that an answer, but cant comment because of my lack of reputation :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the current state of the channels is not announced (it is allegedly hidden for privacy purposes). Therefore, `A` does not know if a route has enough capacity until he tries to make the payment throught that route.

A [recent study](https://diar.co/volume-2-issue-25/) claims that success rate is around 80% for USD 1.2, but only about 1% for transactions larger than 200 USD.

Related question: [In lightning network, is the balance publicly anounced in realtime?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80130/in-lightning-network-is-the-balance-publicly-anounced-in-realtime)